# is it possible to use JavaScriptSpellCheck in jsp pages?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I would like to perform Spell Checking on textarea and like to show invalid words onchange. For this i found JavaScriptSpellCheck plugin but looks it will not support for jsp pages. is it? if, yes please suggest one good plugin to make my work easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are many tools available for spell check in JSP pages.
Use RapidSpellCheck by Keyoti. It is easy to understand and use